# Checking whether the following set is linear continuum

Tags: general-topology

This is problem 5(c) in Section 24 of Munkres' Topology.

> (c) Is the set $[0, 1)\times [0, 1]$ in dictionary order a linear continuum?

So, this set is basically an ordered square with the side $\{1\}\times[0, 1]$ missing. I have seen two solutions up to now, and they both claim that $C:=[0, 1)\times[0, 1]$ is a linear continuum. Recall that a linear continuum is a simply ordered set $L$ satisfying:

- $L$ has the least upper bound property
- If $x<y$, then there exists $z$ such that $x<z<y$.

I can't see why the set $C$ satisfies the first property. Take the set $S=\{(1-\frac{1}{2^n}, 1) | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, a subset of $C$. Yet, the set does not have a least bound on dictionary order on $C$, since it would have to be $(1, 0)$ which is not on the set. Where am I missing something?

Comment: Your example set $S$ is unbounded in $C$! The *least upper bound property* wants every bounded above set to have a least upper bound.

Comment: @martini Thanks for the comment. What does bounded in a set mean, though?

Comment: To phrase it in another way: $S$ does not have any upper bound in $C$. The *least upper bound property* for $C$ is: If $S\subseteq C$ has an upper bound in $C$ (i. e. if there is any $c\in C$ such that $s\le c$ for all $s\in S$), then $S$ has a least upper bound in $C$.

Comment: @martini Oh that clears up. Thank you.

Comment: Forgot *nonempty* in both comments. Only nonempty bounded above sets must have a least upper bound.